# Installing acidbase on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian

I'm having issues to install [acidbase](https://launchpad.net/debian/wheezy/+source/acidbase/1.4.5-3) on Debian Wheezy:

```
apt-get install -y acidbase
```

Throws:

> Unable to locate package acidbase

My `sources.list` looks ok and I've already ran `apt-get update`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another fork of Acid that works in Wheezy? Or should I update to Squeeze?

I can't really find an alternative or solution to this problem. There is this [bug ticket](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=707921) which seems to answer why I can't `apt-get` acidbase anymore. Is there a viable alternative or should I just extract it from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acidbase` was in Debian 6 (squeeze), but was removed, so is not in Debian 7 (wheezy). See  [Debian Package Tracking System - acidbase](http://packages.qa.debian.org/a/acidbase.html) for details of the package's history. The bug report [RM: acidbase -- RoQA; open security issues; unmaintained](http://bugs.debian.org/707921) linked from that page gives the history of the removal.

You can probably install acidbase from squeeze if you want, either by installing the binary e.g. from http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/acidbase or by rebuilding the package source on wheezy.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an working solution.

Download `acidbase_1.4.5.orig.tar.gz` from the link in the question and move it to the web server root (Apache2 defaults to `/var/www`), then extract it:

```
tar xvfz acidbase_1.4.5.orig.tar.gz
```

Open the folder of the extracted files through the web browser (`localhost/base-1.4.5/`) and a wizard will guide you through. A full Acidbase install guide can be found [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/installation-and-configuration-of-intrusion-detection-with-snort-acidbase-mysql-and-apache2-on-ubuntu-9.04-using-spm-p2).